# PHPSpreadSheet no guarda en xls el primer registro

Tags: php, mysql, phpspreadsheet

Mi pregunta es acerca de crear un archivo XLS con PHPSpreadSheet lo logro hacer pero parte desde el segundo registro. Por alguna razón se salta el primero y el origen de los datos es mysql.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione!

Lo que pasa es que en la linea 36 hago un fetch para sacar el nombre del curso y lo toma como un registro y luego en el foreach por alguna razón parte desde el registro 2.